# GCP: How to associate Cloud Function egress with a europe-north1 IP address?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, static-ip-address

**Goal**

I'm using Google Cloud Functions for running my application logic and need to associate egress network traffic with an IP address in region `europe-north1`.

**The problem**

Cloud Functions are not available in region `europe-north1` so I need to keep them in some other, supported region. If I set up an external static IP address in region `europe-north1`, Cloud Function egress doesn't seem to work at all anymore; the network traffic is blocked.

**What I've tried**

My Cloud Functions run just fine in region `europe-west1`, and I have been able to associate egress traffic with a static IP address in region `europe-west1` successfully by following [this GCP guide](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#associate-static-ip). This is what the setup looks like:

```
[Cloud Function] -- [Serverless VPC Access connector]
                          |
                    [VPC network]
                          |
                    [Cloud NAT gateway] -- [Cloud Router] -- [static IP address]
```

In this setup I have all the resources in the same region, `europe-west1`, but that's not what I want, I need the static IP in region `europe-north1`.

If I get a static IP address from region `europe-north1`, the Cloud Router as well as the Cloud NAT gateway need to be in that region, too, and then egress is blocked.

I've tried both of the VPC network Dynamic routing modes, regional and global, to no avail.

Serverless VPC Access connectors are supported in `europe-north1` but they can't be connected to Cloud Functions in other regions (and CFs aren't supported in that region).

I even started setting up a forward proxy on a VM instance but soon realised it's likely not going to work with HTTPS traffic...

How can I route the traffic from Cloud Functions to a static IP in `europe-north1`?

Comment: Why do you need an IP in Europe north 1? Do you already have reserved this IP?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#shared-vpc

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I prefer to not go into the details of why I need the address in that region. And yes, I have reserved a static external IP address in `europe-north1` in GCP.

Comment: @JohnHanley "Shared VPC allows you to export subnets from a VPC network in a host project to other service projects in the same organization." Could you elaborate how using a shared VPC network would solve the problem?

Comment: @Olli, np to not share detail. However, I don't see any solution for this. My solution was "Because an IP is publicly accessible on the Internet, you can reserve it in europe-west1, deploy in europe-west1, and you will be able to reach any service elsewhere".

Comment: Try Load Balancing[(Setting up serverless NEGs)](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/setting-up-serverless-negs) if this is applicable to your goal.

Comment: @JohnMichaelG, is it possible to configure the egress traffic with serverless NEGs? As far as I can tell the docs only discuss ingress.

Comment: You are correct, I though reserved IP address in `europe-north1` then associate it to Cloud Function through LB will be okay. My answer for this issue is same with @guillaumeblaquiere.

Answer (score 0):

Put Extensible Service Proxy V2 (ESPv2) in front of your function. Cloud Run is now available in Hamina (europe-north-1) so this is very convenient way to expose your API from Finland.

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/set-up-cloud-functions-espv2